# reading serial data from arduino using java awt

Tags: java, awt

Here i want to read the data from aruino serial port and i want to display it in the GUI  text box i have created using awt, but i am getting a null pointer exception can anybody please help me out thanks

```
initially i uploaded this code into the arduino and disabled the port 
int val = 0;
int led = 8;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  delay(100);
}

void serialEvent() // To check if there is any data on the Serial line

{
    while (Serial.available())
     {
        val = Serial.parseInt();
         if(val == 1)   //Switch on the LED, if the received value is 1.
         {
             digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
         }
         else if(val == 0) //Switch off the LED, if the received value is 1.
         {
             digitalWrite(led, LOW);
         }     
     }

     Serial.println("Succesfully received.");
   }
```

This is the test class

```
package TestClass;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import Arduino.SerialClass;
import Arduino.SerialClass;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestClass extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
  public static BufferedReader input;
  public static OutputStream output;
  TextField t1;
  Button b1,b2;
  InputStreamReader Ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(Ir);
  public static synchronized void writeData(String data) {
  System.out.println("Sent: " + data);
  try {
    output.write(data.getBytes());
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("could not write to port");
  }
  }

TestClass()
{
    t1=new TextField(20);
    b1=new Button("Probe");
    b2=new Button("Clear");
    add(t1);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,24));
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Mr.Mft");
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);

}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass t=new TestClass();
    SerialClass obj = new SerialClass();
    int c=0;
    obj.initialize();
    input = SerialClass.input;
    output = SerialClass.output;
    obj.close();

 }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    String buttonName=ae.getActionCommand();
    if(buttonName.equals("Probe"))
    {
        try {
           String inputLine=input.readLine();
            t1.setText(""+inputLine);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if(buttonName.equals("Clear"))
    {
            t1.setText("");

    }

}

}
```

This is the serial class:

```
package Arduino;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class SerialClass implements SerialPortEventListener {

public SerialPort serialPort;
/** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {

  "COM4", // Windows
};

public static BufferedReader input;
public static OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
public static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
public static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
  CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
  Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

  //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
  while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
    for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
       if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
          portId = currPortId;
          break;
       }
    }
  }
 if (portId == null) {
   System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
   return;
}

 try {
  // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
  serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
  TIME_OUT);

  // set port parameters
  serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
  SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
  SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
  SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

  // open the streams
  input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
  output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
  char ch = 1;
  output.write(ch);


  // add event listeners
  serialPort.addEventListener(this);
  serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.toString());
}
}

public synchronized void close() {
  if (serialPort != null) {
    serialPort.removeEventListener();
    serialPort.close();
  }
}

public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
    try {
      String inputLine=input.readLine();
      System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
  }

} 

public static synchronized void writeData(String data) {
System.out.println("Sent: " + data);
try {
  output.write(data.getBytes());
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("could not write to port");
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
SerialClass main = new SerialClass();
main.initialize();
Thread t=new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
    //waiting for events to occur and responding to them
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    writeData("2");} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
  }
};
t.start();
System.out.println("Started");
}

public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}
}


I got these error messages 
Dec 24, 2013 1:42:20 PM TestClass.TestClass actionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read(RXTXPort.java:1331)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at TestClass.TestClass.actionPerformed(TestClass.java:78)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
ajava.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
ajava.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
ajava.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

any help appreciated thanks
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: I got these error messages 

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
    at TestClass.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:46)
    at TestClass.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:61)
    Java Result: 1
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
 
    any help appreciated thanks

Comment: I have modied the code i am getting a window but i need to display serial port data on my text field t1 when i press the probe button any help please thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add null objects to the frame in the `TestClass` constructor:

```
add(t1);
add(b1);
add(b2);
```

First you need to initialize them, e.g. `t1 = new TextField();`